# Xamarin Forms Google Auth in iOS causing problem in Azure DevOps

Tags: xamarin.forms, deployment, xamarin.ios, azure-devops, google-authentication

how are you doing?

I have a Xamarin Forms app with facebook authentication.
To publish this app to appstoreconnect, I use an Azure DevOps pipeline (the default template using mac host to perform that).

Recently I tried to provide the google auth as well, using the Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn lib in the iOS proj.
During debbuging, in the simulator, everything runs well.

When I tried to publish the app in the appstoreconnect, using Azure DevOps, I got this logs, in the "Build Xamarin.iOS solution" step:

```
"/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(_CompileToNative target) -> 
  clang : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  error MT5209 : Native linking error : warning: ignoring file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/GTMOAuth2, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/GTMOAuth2 (4 slices) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  error MT5209 : Native linking error : warning: ignoring file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/GoogleSignIn, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/GoogleSignIn (4 slices) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  error MT5209 : Native linking error : warning: ignoring file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID (4 slices) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  error MT5209 : Native linking error : warning: ignoring file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCore, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCore (4 slices) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  error MT5209 : Native linking error : warning: ignoring file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (4 slices) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  error MT5209 : Native linking error : warning: ignoring file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/FirebaseNanoPB, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/FirebaseNanoPB (4 slices) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  error MT5209 : Native linking error : warning: ignoring file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/GoogleToolboxForMac, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/GoogleToolboxForMac (4 slices) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  error MT5209 : Native linking error : warning: ignoring file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/nanopb, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/nanopb (4 slices) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  error MT5209 : Native linking error : warning: ignoring file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/GTMSessionFetcher, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/GTMSessionFetcher (4 slices) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  error MT5209 : Native linking error : warning: ignoring file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/Protobuf, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/Protobuf (4 slices) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  error MT5209 : Native linking error : warning: ignoring file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/GGLCore, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/GGLCore (4 slices) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  error MT5209 : Native linking error : warning: ignoring file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/FirebaseAnalytics, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache/FirebaseAnalytics (4 slices) [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: FIRAnalytics. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: FIRAnalyticsConfiguration. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalyticsConfiguration' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: FIRApp. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: FIRConfiguration. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRConfiguration' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: FIRInstanceID. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRInstanceID' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: FIROptions. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROptions' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GGLConfiguration. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GGLConfiguration' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GGLContext. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GGLContext' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GIDAuthentication. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDAuthentication' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GIDGoogleUser. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDGoogleUser' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GIDProfileData. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDProfileData' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GIDSignIn. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDSignIn' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GIDSignInButton. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GIDSignInButton' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: GMRConfiguration. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMRConfiguration' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5214: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _kFIRInstanceIDScopeFirebaseMessaging. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.ScopeFirebaseMessaging. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5214: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.TokenRefreshNotification. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5214: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _kGIDSignInErrorDomain. This symbol was referenced by the managed member Google.SignIn.SignIn.SignInErrorDomainKey. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries linked. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]
  MTOUCH : error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.150.3/work/1/s/ApolarImoveis/ApolarImoveis.iOS/ApolarImoveis.iOS.csproj]

    145 Warning(s)
    31 Error(s)
```

And that seems to happen with any google integration lib.
So, anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Hi, did you solved this issue? I'm facing something similar :(

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this issue on my build pipeline, but it was working when building locally. I am using `Plugin.GoogleClient` NuGet package to handle Google single sign on.

After adding `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core` and `Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn` to my Xamarin.iOS project, the issues on the build pipeline went away.